# Rating Filters for Layered Navigation in Magento1.9

Tags: php, rating, magento-1.9, layered-navigation

I need to show the product ratings in layered navigation and to filter also in Magento1.9 version.

I have shown a paid extension for Magento1.4. The url is [this](http://www.manadev.com/demo/rating-in-stock-out-of-stock-in-layered-navigation/index.php/?rating=196).

I need this functionality for Ratings in layered Navigation. I have searched the free extension for this functionality a lot, but there is no specific result by which I can do it programmatically also.

If any one knows about this thing, please reply me with giving a solution or any clue.

Comment: Have you tried that extension? What's wrong with it?

Comment: The mentioned link for extension is needed to be pay. I need free extension for this functionality or need to be customized if possible.